# How to use BLPOP, BRPOP operations on multiple queues using node_redis

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am using node_redis ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis ) client to connect to Redis from my NodeJS application. Following my code for BLPOP operation.

```
client.brpop("key1", 5, function(err, data) {
  // deal with err, data
});
```

But my use case needs to listen on multiple keys like key1, key2, some_other_key_1 etc., How can I do that using the `node_redis`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`BRPOP`](https://redis.io/commands/brpop) command supports multiple keys at the same time. If all lists happen to be empty, it will return the first element added to any of the keys if it happens before the timeout.

To do this on **node-redis**, pass all keys and timeout in an array:

```
client.brpop(["key1", "key2", "some_other_key_1", 5], function(err, data) {
    // deal with err, data
    console.log(data.length + " replies:");
    data.forEach(function (reply, i) {
        console.log("    " + i + ": " + reply);
    });
    client.quit();
});
```